# Newtcbtheorem vs Newtheorem: Problem with counters

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, counters

I have a problem with counters: the `newtcbtheorem`'s one conflits with `newtheorem`'s one.
How could I solv my problem? Thank you so much.
I hope my question clear.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems,skins}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% New Exercises

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection] {exercise}{Esercizio}{%
enhanced, colback=red!5!white, colframe=gray, sharpish corners, breakable, fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=green, separator sign={\ ---},#1, description delimiters={$\bigl($}{$\bigr)$}}{ex}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=exercise] {solex}{}{enhanced, colback=red!5!white, colframe=gray, sharpish corners, breakable, separator sign none, fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=green, #1}{solex}

\newtheorem{esercizio}{Esercizio}[subsection]

% Per le soluzioni

\tcbset{exercise ref/.initial=,}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{SolEx}{Soluzione dell'\Exref{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/exercise ref}}}{enhanced, colback=red!5!white, colframe=black, sharpish corners, breakable, separator sign none, fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=orange}{ex}

% Nuove ref

\newcommand{\Exref}[1]{\textcolor{red}{Esercizio} \ref{ex:#1}}

\begin{document}

\Large

\begin{exercise}{Esercizio d'esempio}{EX1}

\end{exercise}

\begin{SolEx*}[exercise ref={EX1}]

\end{SolEx*}

\begin{esercizio}

\end{esercizio}

Problem with counter: I'd like this\\
\textbf{Esercizio 0.0.0.2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) says

[image]

So you have to put tcb-environment `exercise`'s counter into the first optional parameter, which is `tcb@cnt@exercise`.

Using

```tex
\makeatletter
\newtheorem{esercizio}[tcb@cnt@exercise]{Esercizio}
\makeatother
```

instead of

```tex
\newtheorem{esercizio}{Esercizio}[subsection]
```

will work.

[image]